# How to catch an event when iPhone is rebooted in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

What I am trying to do is setup a local notification. The code is working as expected but what if the phone is switched off?

After reading some article on [UILocalNotification when iPhone switched off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573013/uilocalnotification-when-iphone-switched-off) I need to recreate each local notification had been made so I go through this [How to check if iOS device has been rebooted since launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131663/how-to-check-if-ios-device-has-been-rebooted-since-launch), and [How can I detect whether the iphone has been rebooted since last time app started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443601/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-iphone-has-been-rebooted-since-last-time-app-starte), and still could not reach my target.

What I want to know is: is there an event that would be launched when the iPhone is rebooted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misread your sources.

Local notification won't fire when the phone is off (normal it's off).
However, if you have a notification at 3pm, reboot your phone at 2pm, then the notification will fire normally.

Comment: so the **UILocalNotification** will always fire unless the date is expired right ? few!! your really saved me bro !! Thanks :D

Comment: That's it, `UILocalNotification` once scheduled, doesn't need to be recreated.
However, if the phone is off at the fire time, then the notification will never be fired.