# How to detect if the device has just been rebooted?

Tags: ios

I have and application which give data usage in intervals. I want to detect if the device has been rebooted before using the data usage. I tried using mach_absolute_time() but i could not understand anything.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the system uptime like this:

```
let systemUptime = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime; // swift
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].systemUptime; //Objective c
```

You can store it in NSUserDefaults and use it to determine if a reboot occurred.

Please also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443601/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-iphone-has-been-rebooted-since-last-time-app-starte) thread for more information.

**Swift 3:**

```
let systemUptime: TimeInterval = ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime
```

Comment: All those techniques detect a reboot when the user changes the phone's date/time. These techniques would only work with a reliable system boot timestamp, and if that information were available, there would be no need of these hacks.

Comment: @piojo That information is not explicitly available, but it can be easily calculated; see my answer below

Comment: This will miss a reboot detection if it is ran a second time longer after a second reboot than the first time it ran after the first reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one I made. It takes the current time in GMT and the time since last reboot to extrapolate a date for when the device was last restarted. Then it keeps track of this date in memory using NSUserDefaults. Enjoy!

```
#define nowInSeconds CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()//since Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT
#define secondsSinceDeviceRestart ((int)round([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]))
#define storage [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
#define DISTANCE(__valueOne, __valueTwo) ((((__valueOne)-(__valueTwo))>=0)?((__valueOne)-(__valueTwo)):((__valueTwo)-(__valueOne)))

+(BOOL)didDeviceReset {
    static BOOL didDeviceReset;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    int currentRestartDate = nowInSeconds-secondsSinceDeviceRestart;
    int previousRestartDate = (int)[((NSNumber *)[storage objectForKey:@"previousRestartDate"]) integerValue];
    int dateVarianceThreshold = 10;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (!previousRestartDate || DISTANCE(currentRestartDate, previousRestartDate) > dateVarianceThreshold) {
            didDeviceReset = YES;
        } else {
            didDeviceReset = NO;
        }
    });
    [storage setObject:@(currentRestartDate) forKey:@"previousRestartDate"];
    [storage synchronize];
    return didDeviceReset;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc) _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_. Also, don't give the same answer to multiple questions. Just provide a link in the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391327/123632

Comment: @AshleyMills Our app supports iOS6+ so we need to have synchronize incase user enters background shortly after (attempting to force quit app to bypass device reset detection). Synchronize only became un-necessary after iOS7. Please don't downvote for things like this