# Real System time on iPhone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm building an app that include in app purchase (subscription based): the user is required a subscription to consult more that X time a given section of the app per week, however i'm facing a problem as the user can bypass the limitation by changing the time of his iPhone.

I know that one solution would be to verify the time on a server side, but the app is to run without internet connexion...

S how can i get the REAL device time (NOT THE USER DEFINED TIME).

thanks.

Comment: Im thinking about using NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification to track date change after each subscription so that i always get the real time interval since the last subscription, i think that this may work... your thought on how to use this?

Comment: Hi Clide Do you get any solution for this ???

Comment: Hi clide and @Apple, I've been trying to find the same thing. I've posted some results of my researches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17413277/1431728). So far nothing satisfying, but stay tuned...